# How to change primary group?

Tags: group

I have a user like this:

```
uid=501(ironsand) gid=500(foo) groups=500(foo),10(wheel),497(git),501(ironsand)
```

And to change primary group to ironsand like `gid=501(ironsand)`, I typed this command:

```
sudo usermod -g ironsand ironsand
```

It changed groups order but didn't change main group like:

```
uid=501(ironsand) gid=500(foo) groups=501(ironsand),10(wheel),497(git),500(foo)
```

I thought someone already asked a question like this, but I couldn't find one.

How can I change primary group?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Usually you do it like the following.

To assign a primary group to an user:

```
$ usermod -g primarygroupname username
```

To assign secondary groups to a user (`-a` keeps already existing secondary groups intact otherwise they'll be removed):

```
$ usermod -a -G secondarygroupname username
```

From man-page:

```
...
-g (primary group assigned to the users)
-G (Other groups the user belongs to)
-a (Add the user to the supplementary group(s))
...
```

Comment: For secondary groups, if adding instead of given a exhaustive list, don't forget the flag `-a`

Comment: And don't forget that you have to log out and back in again for the change to become effective

Comment: The -a flag is very important, because you can accidentaly remove user accounts from the `sudo`ers list by forgetting it.

Comment: need close all login session, otherwise it will not work

Comment: How do you do this without root access?